# Why is my computer randomly restarting? How can I fix it?

Tags: windows, power-supply, crash, desktop-computer, reset

I have a custom built desktop computer that I've been using since about a year ago. The main specs are:

- ASUS P8Z68-V LE Motherboard
- Intel Core i7 2600k
- Corsair Vengeance 16GB Ram
- ASUS ENGTX570 GPU
- Corsair TX650M PSU

I was running an overclock of 4.4ghz for my cpu (I have a Hyper212 EVO) and 1600mhz for my RAM but have it currently turned off due to my issues. I am also currently running Windows 8 but this problem occured in Windows 7 too.

**Basically my issue is that seemingly randomly, with no pattern my PC will reset itself and ASUS Anti-Surge will alert me that something went wrong.** This issue is not related to system stress. I can run it fine for an hour maxxed out on Prime95 then later I can be watching a mere YouTube video when it will randomly reset. This has been occurring probably for the last two weeks and it seems to be getting worse. I believe this might be related to the power supply but when I monitor it in the bios and in Windows it appears to be putting out the proper voltages. Also possibly related or not but my Nvidia drivers frequently temporarily fail and then warn me of some kind of kernel error? If I have to buy a new power supply that is what I'll do but I want to make damn sure that's the only issue at hand. Thank you everyone in advance, please help me diagnose the issue and tell me what I can do to fix it. If you need any additional info about my setup please ask me.

Comment: Have you tried memory test with something like "memtest"?

Comment: No, how would I do that?

Comment: e.g. download from [here](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) which suits you.. usb instalator or cd iso.. boot from that device and let it run for several hours..

Comment: After burning iso or prepairing usb. Restart pc and select boot from (usb or cd) (by pressing F12 at startup or setting in BIOS) it will automatically start testing your RAM, after several passes, you'll see if there are some errors..

Comment: After running memtest for 8 hours it completed 4 passes with 0 errors. I guess I can now rule out the memory, what else could be causing my problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psu has finally failed. I'm ordering a new one today. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

With kernel related errors, you can be almost certain the issue lies with memory errors. If you have maxed out the overclocking of your CPU, it's highly likely you've affected the physical memory modules. If you have some spare memory modules laying around (even if they are lower capacity), do swap the existing modules for the spare modules you have sitting around.

"DON'T FORGET TO GROUND YOURSELF" before touching the memory, otherwise the test maybe flawed. If the auxiliary memory tests out to have found the solution, buy some new modules, throw the old memory away AND reduce the overclocked CPU back to it's factory speed. Unfortunately an overclocked Intel CPU can keep like a footprint of it's former high speed and spike out the new memory if you attempt to increase the speed.

Comment: After running memtest for 8 hours it completed 4 passes with 0 errors.